# Return multiple columns of data from a single column with different WHERE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to output the following table from my database

```
    DateTime   |  Measure 1  |  Measure 2
    5-5-2011   |   35        |    45
    4-5-2011   |   23        |    56
    3-5-2011   |   22        |    56
```

My database in question contains data in this approximate layout

```
    DateTime   |  Values     |  ID
    5-5-2011   |   35        |  Measure 1
    5-5-2011   |   45        |  Measure 2
    4-5-2011   |   23        |  Measure 1
    4-5-2011   |   56        |  Measure 2
    3-5-2011   |   22        |  Measure 1
    3-5-2011   |   56        |  Measure 2
```

Is there anyway I can get my desired output in a single SQL query. I can easily obtain my data through multiple select queries i.e.

```
  SELECT DateTime, Values AS Measure 1 FROM database.table WHERE ID='Measure 1'
  SELECT DateTime, Values AS Measure 2 FROM database.table WHERE ID='Measure 2'
```

However I need the data in a single query to build pretty pictures in MSSQL Report Builder.

The database in question contains millions of values for hundreds of measures. I am running MSSQL 2008.

I've looked into Union, Case etc but couldn't get any method to work correctly.

Hopefully someone can help me. I'm stumped and don't know the correct phrases to search for help on this problem. If I can crack this nut then i'll pretty much have all the tools to do everything I want to do.

Thank you in advance

Comment: is DateTime unique in your table?

Comment: Have you looked at Group By ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you not find some other name for the ID column that's also a reserved word? :-)

```
SELECT
    [DateTime],
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID='Measure 1' THEN [Values] END) as Measure1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID='Measure 2' THEN [Values] END) as Measure2
FROM
    [table]
GROUP BY
    [DateTime]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The database was just an example, but i'm sure you probably new that :) Your query makes absolute sense, its probably because its after midnight where I am :/ Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Create Table #Measure1 (DateTime datetime,Values int)
Insert INTO #Measure1 
Select DateTime,Values from ABC where ID = 'Measure 1'

Create Table #Measure2 (DateTime datetime,Values int)
Insert INTO #Measure1 
Select DateTime,Values from ABC where ID = 'Measure 2'

Select ABC.DateTime, #Measure1.Values AS 'Measure 1',#Measure2.Values AS 'Measure 2'
FROM ABC,#Measure1,#Measure2
WHERE ABC.DateTime  = #Measure1.DateTime AND #Measure1.DateTime = #Measure2.DateTime
DROP Table #Measure1; DROP Table #Measure2;
```

Here we are tring to create 2 temporary tables and by using inner join tring to get desired result set.Also it would be better if DateTime column has unique values against Measure1 and Measure2 to get desired output. Here I have assumed the name of data table as 'ABC'